# How can I take mulitple values in input text field from user

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I am trying to get it to take multiple values in input text field. From my user where they can insert multiple name in single text field.

Answer (score 2):

show a message below to input box to user that 'enter your value and separate them by comma'. and in back end manage it using coma separate string to array php function and do as per your need

Comment: thank for advice sir but i need (http://www.naukri.com/ ) like this when we type own skills .

Comment: ok got your point so its called tagged in Visit                   https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager

Answer (score 0):

User has to enter names or values by separating commas(,) or any special character.

```
var namesArray = document.getElementById("names").value.split(',');
```

So you get all the names which are separated by comma. `nameArray` filled names.

This is not an answer but one way of doing it. But alter it according to your requirement.

Comment: thank for advice sir but i need (http://www.naukri.com/ ) like this when we type own skills .